# Sql View To Search Through A Table Or Another View

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Good day

May you kindly assist me, I have a SQL view That has txDate, reference, Amount
like

```
  select TxDate, Reference, Amount
    FROM Transactions
```

Then I have a Table called Period, that has PeriodId, StartDate and EndDate

so the period is by month, 
LIKE

```
   PeriodID           StartDate               EndDate
     1                 2017/01/01              2017/01/31
     2                 2017/02/01              2017/02/29
     3                 2017/03/01              2017/03/31
     4                 2017/04/01              2017/04/30
```

And so on up until December which will be period 12,

So i want to have the Query to Search the Period table using the txDate in my SQL View, for Example

```
        if txDate is '2017/02/25'
```

The Query must return the PeriodID in Which the TxDate is Between StartDate and EndDate, so in this instance it should be 2.

So my result should be something like this

```
    txDate             Reference             Amount          PeriodID
    2017/02/25          INVOO1               2000               2
    2017/01/04          REC002                 30               1
    2017/03/05          SALE                 5000               3
```

How do I make that JOIN on Searching that Table to bring the PEriodID onto my SQL View...??

Comment: That can only work if you are 100% certain that in your period table there are no periods that overlap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure the start- and end-date within the Period table never overlap and that there's always a record in the Period table that matches your TxDate, it's quite simple:

```
SELECT tran.TxDate,
       tran.Reference,
       tran.Amount,
       peri.idPeriod
FROM   Transactions tran
JOIN   Period       peri
  ON   tran.TxDate BETWEEN peri.PeriodStartDate and peri.PeriodEndDate,
```